# selected date input from user always stored as "1970" in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, datetime

I have a problem regarding saving the time that the user selects in the input[date] field with AngularJS and posting to Mysql DB.

In the console when I log the data object that contains all input fields values the date seems to be in the right format "2016-12-28" but in my MySQL DB the values is always stored as "1970-01-01".

My frontend:

```
 <input type="date" placeholder="Datum" class="form-control" ng-model="event.the_date">
```

AngularJS:

```
 $scope.AddEvent = function(){

    var eventDate = new Date($scope.event.the_date).toISOString().slice(0,10);

      var data = {
            time:$scope.event.the_time,
            date:eventDate, <-- this gets the right value from the input field ex. "2016-12-28"
            location:$scope.event.location,
            place:$scope.event.place
        }
//continue with $http.post
```

My backend:

```
  $params = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
  $date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($params['the_date']));
try{

$sql = "INSERT INTO events (the_date,the_time,place,location) VALUES (:the_date,:the_time,:place,:location)";
$query = $con->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array(
    ':the_date'=>$date, <-- this get always the 1970 date!
    ':the_time'=>$params['the_time'],
    ':place'=>$params['place'],
    ':location'=>$params['location'],
));

}catch(PDOException $e){
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: where were you logging it from exacly?

Comment: i logged it first from the  var data = {
            time:$scope.event.the_time,
            date:eventDate,
            location:$scope.event.location,
            place:$scope.event.place
        }

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming

```
$date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($params['the_date']));
```

should be

```
$date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($params['date']));
```

Are you getting the correct data when you `var_dump($params)`?

Comment: that was the problem, i used ['the_date'] instead of ['date']